# Center an off screen SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a screen with a **horizontally centered circle** that is bigger than the actual screen's width. Unfortunately, I do not know how to **center it horizontally** and **pin it to the top**. Is there an easy way to achieve such results with SwiftUI?

```
struct DemoView: View {
    private let circleBackgroundPercentage: CGFloat = 1.3
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * circleBackgroundPercentage, height: geometry.size.height * circleBackgroundPercentage, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
            Text("Demo")
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image: The expected result]] [image: The current result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is possible approach to solve such kind to task.

Prepared with Xcode 12.4/iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            Color.yellow
                .clipShape(Circle())
            Color.clear
        }
        .scaleEffect(1.8)   // << tune factor as needed !!
        Text("Demo")
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use offset(x:y:)

> Offset this view by the specified horizontal and vertical distances. - [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/offset(x:y:))

Align horizontally in the center.

```
.offset(x: -(((geometry.size.width * circleBackgroundPercentage) - geometry.size.width)) / 2)
```

---

You can use a similar technique for `y` position to pin the circle at the top.

---

You can also use `position(x:y:)`. Fore more info, read this articel
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/absolute-positioning-for-swiftui-views

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that but isn't there an easier solution without calculating the offset manually?