# SwiftUI Fixed constraint from bottom of view to top of screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

Question: How to set fixed "constraint" from buttom of view to top of the screen?

My problem explanation:
I'm trying to implement such element on screen:

[image]

Rounded shape which has stable height in all screens
I use Oval to draw it like

```
public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Ellipse()
                .fill(Color.surfacePrimary)
                .frame(width: 546, height: 364)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -20)
        
            Text("Text")
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
                .foregroundColor(.onPrimary)
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 20)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

        Text("This text should be right below yellow shape, and it is, but on screens with not rectangle forms, on screens with rectangle form, it pops up on yellow zone")

        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Problem: that it works good on iphones 11, 12. But on 8, 8+, SE (where screens have right rectangle form) frame of ZStack move on top but Ellipse left on the same place. And Views which should be below yellow zone move to yellow zone.

UPD: I solved problem with different heights of StatusBar, but now I have another problem which was not observable before.

My new code:

```
public var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Ellipse()
            .fill(.yellow)
        Text("Text")
            .padding(.bottom, 42)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
    .frame(width: 546, height: 364)
    .position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, y: Spacing.padding_0_5)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

This ZStack fills almost all height of the screen. But I expect it should has fixed height. It looks like:

(hmmm ... some problem with uploading image)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66371575/12299030?

Comment: Partly. I used .position() to place ellipse on the top, but this solution became cause of another problem.  ZStack fills almost all screen. I will add this as a comment ...